# Como levar um método da Entidade de Domínio para camadas superiores

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, ddd

Olá,
Tenho a seguinte entidade de domínio.

```
public class Cliente{
    [Key]
    public string CPF{get; set;}
    public string Nome{get; set;}

    //Outras propriedades

    public void Sacar(Conta conta, decimal valor){
        conta.Saldo -=valor;
    }
    public void Depositar(Conta conta, decimal valor){
        conta.Saldo+=valor;
    }
}
```

Estou trabalhando numa arquitetura [ddd](/questions/tagged/ddd). Como eu vou mapear isso na minha camada [application](/questions/tagged/application) e utilizar na camada [presentation](/questions/tagged/presentation)?

Agradeço a todos que puderem colaborar,
abraço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No DDD, quando precisamos criar uma Entidade complexa é necessário utilizarmos uma fábrica (o que o DDD chama de Factory) de objetos para que possamos reutilizá-la ao longo do projeto.

Assim, você pode criar uma classe abstrata contendo métodos que retornam objetos consistentes (nesse caso um objeto Cliente), com um ponto único de manutenção.

Criada a fábrica, você pode utiliza-la na camada de Aplicação. Mas se quizer deixar seu código ainda mais desacoplado, você pode criar uma interface com as assinaturas dos métodos de sua fábrica e mapear sua fábrica para as demais camadas utilizando IoC/DI.

---

**Edição:**

Você pode continuar utilizando o AutoMapper normalmente para realizar o mapeamento entre Cliente e ClienteViewModel, até porque o objetivo do AutoMapper é transformar/mapear objetos, evitando o trabalho manual.

Porém, para chamar métodos dos seus objetos de Domínio - como o método Sacar() - você pode implementar o que o DDD chama de Serviço. Você cria na camada de Domínio uma interface IClienteService e sua respectiva ClienteService que implementa os métodos a serem consumidos pelas demais camadas *(inclusive sugiro remover os métodos da entidade Cliente e criar um serviço delegando essa responsabilidade de saque/depósito para IContaService/ContaService, pois, imagine se a conta não tiver saldo. Você vai ter que tratar uma série de situações como essa que não são da responsabilidade da entidade Cliente, mas sim de Conta)*.

Na sua camada de Apresentação (pelo que percebi Asp.net MVC) você pode receber essa interface no construtor do seu Controller via IoC/DI como mencionei anteriormente.

Abaixo algumas considerações que achei pertinentes reforçar, pois após ler seu comentário fiquei com dúvida se já está claro para você:

- Sua entidade do Domínio não deve possuir qualquer dependência com um
  framework externo. Logo, retire [key] e outras referências a
  frameworks externos de sua entidade de domínio.
- Não há problemas em sua camada de Apresentação conhecer seus objetos
  de Domínio. Teria problemas o inverso (camada de Domínio conhecer a
  camada de Apresentação).

Comment: Criei a interface ICliente. Porém minha camada de Apresentação não conhece o Domínio, por esse motivo mapeei as entidades de domínio para application utilizando AutoMapper. Então na Application eu tenho ClienteViewModel. Então independente deste mapeamento eu devo chamar sacar() de ICliente?

Comment: Como você mencionou sobre o AutoMapper no seu comentário, vou editar a resposta considerando a sua utilização.